Eclipse Scout - pnpm install failure in Eclipse IDE
I'm experiencing some difficulty with getting the helloscout demo application to work. I'm using the Eclipse IDE and I was following the steps outlined in the Hello Scout Classic guide on https://eclipsescout.github.io/scout-docs/24.2/getstarted/helloscout.html
When I try to run the project, it fails on pnpm install and says the reason is a self-signed certificate in the certificate chain.
This is the console output below:
Running 'pnpm install' in C:\Users\JD\eclipse-scout-demos-workspace\helloworld\helloscout
Scope: all 2 workspace projects
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/pnpm failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pnpm\dist\pnpm.cjs:73748:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:101:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:504:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@eclipse-scout%2Freleng failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pnpm\dist\pnpm.cjs:73748:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:101:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:504:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@eclipse-scout%2Feslint-config failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pnpm\dist\pnpm.cjs:73748:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:101:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:504:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pnpm\dist\pnpm.cjs:73748:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:101:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:504:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@eclipse-scout%2Fcli failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pnpm\dist\pnpm.cjs:73748:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:101:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:504:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2Fjquery failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pnpm\dist\pnpm.cjs:73748:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:101:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:504:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pnpm\dist\pnpm.cjs:73748:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:101:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:504:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@eclipse-scout%2Fcore failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pnpm\dist\pnpm.cjs:73748:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:101:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:504:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@eclipse-scout%2Ftsconfig failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pnpm\dist\pnpm.cjs:73748:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:101:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:504:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)


Can anyone help me with solving this problem?
Cheers,
JDaniel

Maybe you could try updating NodeJS or the certificate stores in your OS.
